# HttpClient.SendRequestAsync triggering StackOverflow

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I've been coding a library that contains the most of the basic funtions from data handling from online services to storage handling and I've been stuck in a method that should upload an image to a host that would return the path to the file.

The problem is that when I try to make the call, the app crahses due to stack overflow.

Here is the complete method:

```
public static async Task<WebResult> UploadImage( WebHost webHost, Object webPath, String webQuery, IRandomAccessStream imageStream ) {
    if (!AllowNetworkConnectivity) {
        return new WebResult( false, true, null );
    }

    HttpClient
        httpClient = new HttpClient();

    HttpMultipartFormDataContent
        httpMultipartContent = new HttpMultipartFormDataContent();

    HttpStreamContent
        httpStreamContent = new HttpStreamContent( imageStream );

    httpStreamContent.Headers.Add( "Content-Type", "application/octet-stream" );
    httpMultipartContent.Add( httpMultipartContent );

    try {
        HttpRequestMessage
            httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage( HttpMethod.Post, new Uri( WebServerUrl( /* ! */ ) ) );

        Dictionary<String, String>
            webCredentialsDictionary = WebServerAuthenticationCredentials( webHost ) as Dictionary<String, String>;

        foreach (KeyValuePair<String, String> credentialEntry in webCredentialsDictionary) {
            httpRequest.Headers.Add( credentialEntry );
        }

        httpRequest.Content = httpMultipartContent;

        /* THE STACK OVERFLOW EXCEPTION IS TRIGGERED HERE */
        HttpResponseMessage
            httpResponse = await httpClient.SendRequestAsync( httpRequest );

        httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        return new WebResult( true, true, null );
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        AppController.ReportException( exception, "Unable to upload image." );

        return new WebResult( false, true, null );
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the stack trace look like? The cause *might* be further up the stack

Comment: There isn't anything wrong with it, it seem. It only contains the calls to this method, and the 3 from the initial button click event, and then a bunch of methods from the `mscorlib.ni`, but I would assume that the stack trace I'm seeing is the typical one from mobile apps.

Comment: `httpMultipartContent.Add(httpMultipartContent);`?

Comment: Thanks @kennyzx! That was causing the StackOverflowException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The origin of the StackOverflowException was here:

```
httpMultipartContent.Add( httpMultipartContent );
```

I was adding the object to itself, which can be self explanatory. I've swapped the variables, this is what it should look like:

```
httpMultipartContent.Add( httpStreamContent );
```